# Laravel Sanctum 401 Unauthorized Response

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, single-page-application

I have a laravel application on a docker container at http://laravel.test. I have a VueJS SPA that is being served on http://localhost:8080. The SPA first makes a get request to http://laravel.test/sanctum/csrf-cookie and then makes a POST request to http://laravel.test/api/login . The User gets authenticated.

However after that any request that I make to routes under the auth:sanctum middleware for e.g

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')→get('/products',[ProductController::class,'index']);
```

I get the Message

```
xhr.js?1a5c:220          GET http://laravel.test/api/products 401 (Unauthorized)
```

If I remove this route from auth:sanctum middleware the route works fine.

The .env files consists of the following configuration

```
APP_URL=http://laravel.test
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=laravel.test
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://localhost:8080
```

The cors.php contents are

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:8080'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

And here is the Kernel.php

```
 'api' => [
        EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
```

I am using VueJs as an SPA and axios to make API Calls. Axios configuration include

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

I am using nginx on laradock, Laravel 9 and VueJs 3 if that info is of any use. However I have tried it on apache with the same result. I have tried php artisan serve and its still not working. (I changed the parameters of .env to reflect the platform change obviously)

I have searched again for about a week on the Internet and StackOverflow. However I have not been able to resolve this problem.

Can anyone help me out with this. What am I doing wrong. I have followed the official laravel documentation. I am trying to use Sanctum SPA Authentication and not token authentication.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance; but If you set allowed origins to localhost,  wouldn't non-localhost ips not be authorized?

Comment: Shouldn't the allowed origins be restricted to the designated front-end app?. And anyways i have tried allowed_origins' => '*' and it still gives the same error

Comment: I think you should pass AUTH token to authorize the route

Comment: Sanctum SPA Authentication doesn't require Token. At least that is my understanding from the docs.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#spa-authentication
In order to authenticate, your SPA and API must share the same top-level domain. However, they may be placed on different subdomains. Additionally, you should ensure that you send the Accept: `application/json` header with your request.

Comment: I've tried it on artisan server too. That hosts it on localhost, still not working

Answer (score 1):

*tl;dr* In order to make Sanctum work, the server and client have to be on the same top-level domain, different ports are ok. For local development with Sanctum, `localhost` is the easiest solution as [Laravel Breeze](https://github.com/laravel/breeze-next) package recommended.

Let's assume you're running frontend on port `8080` and backend on port `8000`.

1. In `.env`

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:8080
```

2. In `config/sanctum.php`

```php
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:8080,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : '',
        env('FRONTEND_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('FRONTEND_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),
```

*notice port 8080 and 8000 in the above example.*

3. Make sure configs are cached properly:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Your frontend seemed right so just check two configs above and reverse others to default.